# EditText delete key not registering on first keydown

Tags: android, android-edittext, keylistener, keydown

My problem is this;

I have an edit text and am using setKeyListener and creating a new NumberKeyListener.  In this on keydown when a number is hit it works as expected, but when the delete/backspace button is hit, it does not register on the first X attempts, but on X + 1 it will, where X is the number, of other keys i've hit.  For example if i entered 5, then 6, then 7, my edittext would read 567, if i hit delete, nothing happens, hit it twice more, still nothing, on the 4th hit, it will finally delete the 7 and be 56.  It's very strange, because i have a log statement in the keydown callback and it seems like its not even being triggered on the first 3 presses?

Any suggestions are appreciated.

UPDATE: I've noticed if I click off of the edittext and back onto it, my deletes will register on the first click.  Is there some sort of keystroke buffer associated with edittexts that needs to be cleared or something?

```
 myedittext.setKeyListener(new NumberKeyListener() {        
       @Override
       public int getInputType() {
           return InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER;
       }

       @Override
       public boolean onKeyDown(View view, Editable content, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
           if (keyCode >= KeyEvent.KEYCODE_0 && keyCode <= KeyEvent.KEYCODE_9) {
               //logic here
           } else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL) {
               Log.i("DEBUG","delete key hit");
               //more logic here
           }
           Log.i("DEBUG","key was pressed");
           update();
           return true;
       }

       @Override
       protected char[] getAcceptedChars() {
           return new char[]{'0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'};
       }
   });
```

With the code above I removed all of my logic and `update()` calls from within the keylistener, all it is, is just the logging prints, and I am seeing the same behavior, that it does not seem to recognize the first x presses of delete.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you please add some code to your post?

Comment: Post your Key Listener and relevant subsequent code please.

Comment: This would only work for hard keys, not soft keys.  Taken from http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/method/BaseKeyListener.html:
 
As for all implementations of KeyListener, this class is only concerned with hardware keyboards. Software input methods have no obligation to trigger the methods in this class.

Answer (score 1):

Note that there is no guarantee of receiving key events, including KEYCODE_DEL, *unless* you override onCreateInputConnection() in your view, and then return TYPE_NULL to the invoking IME as your InputType.  An example can be found here:

[Android - cannot capture backspace/delete press in soft. keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18581636/android-cannot-capture-backspace-delete-press-in-soft-keyboard/19980975#19980975)

***However***, I would *not* use key events at all if you are overriding EditText, because EditText already directly supports your purposes by providing an InputFilter facility:

```
myEditText.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{
  //Filter this so that it removes everything that is not a digit.
  new InputFilter() {
    @Override
    public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start,
                               int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
      //This is filtering ONE character at a TIME, as the user types them.
      String sourceString = source.toString();
      String sourceStringDigits = sourceString.replaceAll("[^0123456789]", "");
      return sourceStringDigits;
    }
  }
};
```

The above should filter your text without interfering with backspace key (delete) processing, which is handled by EditText itself.

Answer (score 0):

`NumberKeyListener` extends `BaseKeyListener`

Did you try overriding `backspace()`?

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/method/BaseKeyListener.html#backspace%28android.view.View,%20android.text.Editable,%20int,%20android.view.KeyEvent%29

> Performs the action that happens when you press the KEYCODE_DEL key in a TextView. If there is a selection, deletes the selection; otherwise, deletes the character before the cursor, if any; ALT+DEL deletes everything on the line the cursor is on.
>   Returns

```
true if anything was deleted; false otherwise.
```

Make sure you call `super.basckspace();` to have the right behavior.

---

I don't have access to an SDK now to test it, but add this to your Listener:

```
@Override
boolean backspace(View view, Editable content, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    Log.d("NumberKeyListener","backspace() called");
    return super.backspace();
}
```

From what I understand of the wording and BaseKeyListener.java code, it is a callback that responds when the delete key was pressed.

Comment: Correct me if i'm wrong, but backspace() is a means to effectively simulate a KEYCODE_DEL keydown event?  How will using this allow me to correct the issue that when the user presses delete/backspace it does not register?

Comment: @Siloid check my updated response. I believe it is a callback for the listener, not intended to simulate the keystroke (there's `KeyEvent.dispatch()` for that). As I said above, I'm unable to test it right now, but it is a short enough code for you to give it a try.